# how to edit in one place and auto refer to other place

Tags: miktex, grammar

this question's title may not clearly. my english expression is not good.
take an example to convey my problem:

```
   \someorder{a}{\paragraph{1999}ABCD}
   \someorder{a}
```

I expect after compile this code , it will show two same paragraph, the second one will auto refers to the fist one

Comment: Maybe you are interested in using `\label` and `\ref`?

Comment: Could you please also explain what ` \someorder` is supposed to do / how it is defined?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211888/is-there-any-way-i-can-define-a-variable-in-latex

Comment: @ Hiwi Makro thank you,`\def`and`\newcommand` is useful

Answer (score 1):

Based on @leandriis comment, this might be what you are looking for is [Lable/Reference](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing).

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

This is some dummy Text, don't mind me.

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
        1+1 = 2
    \end{equation}    

Please consider equation \ref{eq:1}. 

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{1.png}
    \caption{Some Picture}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

This also works for some reference for pictures \ref{fig:1}.

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: example]

This works for a lot more than just equations and figures, but I hope you get the idea.